# Pie Chart,Bar Chart in ASP.Net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, charts

I want to draw pie chart and Bar Chart in my asp.net application to show the annual reports in detail. Is there is any free tools available for this?

I have seen white label theme graphs from forest theme, but these are paid versions. 
[image: Pie Chart Sample]
[image: Bar Chart Sample]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pie chart example:

```
<%@ Page language="c#" debug="true" %>
<%@ import Namespace = "csASPNetGraph" %>
<%
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.Expires = 0;
Response.Clear();
GraphClass Graph = new GraphClass();
Graph.Title = "Pie Chart Example";
Graph.AddData("Item 1", 17, "ff0000");
Graph.AddData("Item 2", 28, "00ff00");
Graph.AddData("Item 3", 5, "0000ff");
Graph.GraphType = 0;
Graph.GraphToBrowser(1);
%>
```

Bar chart example:

```
  <%@ Page language="c#" debug="true" %>
    <%@ import Namespace = "csASPNetGraph" %>
    <%
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.Expires = 0;
    Response.Clear();
    GraphClass Graph = new GraphClass();
    Graph.Title = "Bar Chart Example";
    Graph.TitleX = 120;
    Graph.ShowBarTotal = true;
    Graph.AddData("Item 1", 17, "ff0000");
    Graph.AddData("Item 2", 28, "00ff00");
    Graph.AddData("Item 3", 5, "0000ff");
    Graph.GraphType = 1;
    Graph.GraphToBrowser(1);
    %>
```

Refer following link:

http://www.chestysoft.com/aspnetgraph/manual.htm

Comment: Thanks Parekh, But Karl Anderson also suggested the same thing above. We cant show rich tool tip with customization using this server controls. So, i decided to go for client side chart controls. So, if there is any free client-side tools avail for the same, please share with me.

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET 4.0 and later, there is a built-in chart control, it is available as a separate download in ASP.NET 3.5 SP1.

You can drag a Chart (`<asp:Chart>`) control right from the `Data` section of the toolbox onto your .aspx page.

Read [Using Microsoft's Chart Controls In An ASP.NET Application: Getting Started](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020203246/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/072209-1.aspx) for a tutorial.

Comment: Yes Karl, but as per the UI these are not looking good and difficult to customize . I have added one sample image from theme forest and i want the same rich text ui and should be easy to customize.